# MVH Helpers and intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

I was working hard on a problem yesterday. I had e pre-compiled dll (project name ie: MyHtmlHelpers) containing helpers and lot of other classes.

I had the assembly referenced in the web project and the all "standard"-helpers showed up in intellisense but, even though I added the namespace to both web.config in the root and in the views-folder nothing worked. When running the project helpers works, but not in intellisense.

I added a new class and wrote a new html helper inside the web project, added the namespace to web.config. And that worked.

After some hours add tried my last card, adding the MyHtmlHelpers-project to the same solution as my webproject. That did the trick. I diden't change anything in the configs just added the project to the same solution and changed the reference to point at the project insted of the compiled dll.

Isen't that strange? A VS-bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that happen to me also. For me is was more related to a Generic Version of my helper rather. The intellisense worked if I have no @model defined in the view but failed where I had strongly-typed View.

Sometimes this helped: deleting the bin folder and doing a build.

My helper from a different assembly is now working fine and shows up in intellisense all the time.